# What is LocalizedFileNames in desktop.ini?

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop.ini

I have a desktop.ini in a folder, with contents reading:

```
[LocalizedFileNames]
Pat2Train_5_0.mat=@Pat2Train_5_0,0
Pat2Train_4_1.mat=@Pat2Train_4_1,0
...  # same format for other rows, just different numbers
```

What does this do? There are hundreds of files in the folder, and only a few have corresponding entries in the .ini, yet they look indistinguishable from those not in the .ini:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference would be much more obvious if you used a display language other than English. *LocalizedFileNames* (and the equivalent for folders, *LocalizedResourceName*) allow for those shortcuts and folders that are created by default to have a constant file system name (the English name, regardless of the language version of Windows) while the display name (within the Windows shell) can reflect the user's preferred language.

For example, every language version will have identical copies of Explorer.exe, but a different, languge-specific version of the resource file, shell32.dll.